# boost python code involving both static and overloaded member functions

Tags: python, c++, boost, static, overloading

I'm trying to compile some boost python code involving both static and overloaded member functions. Any hint? I just can't get it compiled using pointers on functions (never done it before) but may be there is another track to follow?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/raw_function.hpp>


namespace python = boost::python;


class ORM
{
public:
  static void print() {std::cout << "Fou statique!!!!" << std::endl;}
  static void print(std::string st) {std::cout << st << std::endl;}
  static void print(std::string st1, std::string st2) {std::cout << st1 << std::endl; std::cout << st2 << std::endl;}
};

void (ORM::*print1)() = &ORM::print;
void (ORM::*print2)(std::string st) = &ORM::print;
void (ORM::*print3)(std::string st1, std::string st2) = &ORM::print;


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(politopy)
{
  python::class_<ORM>("ORM")
    .def("print", &ORM::print1).staticmethod("print")
    .def("print", &ORM::print2).staticmethod("print")
    .def("print", &ORM::print3).staticmethod("print")
;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes worked for me:
You need `#include <string>` to use `std::string`. You also do not need to assign your function pointers as members of `ORM`, along with just having the parameter types in your function pointer assignments. When you declare `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE()` the input **must** match your library name (ie `libpolitopy`). Also, always initialize Python from C++ by using `Py_Initialize()`. Finally, you only need to include the `.staticmethod()` tag once on your final declaration of `print`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/raw_function.hpp>

namespace python = boost::python;

class ORM
{
public:
    static void print() {std::cout << "Fou statique!!!!" << std::endl;}
    static void print(std::string st) {std::cout << st << std::endl;}
    static void print(std::string st1, std::string st2) { std::cout << st1 << std::endl; std::cout << st2 << std::endl;}
};

void (*print1)() = &ORM::print;
void (*print2)(std::string) = &ORM::print;
void (*print3)(std::string, std::string) = &ORM::print;


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libpolitopy)
{
    Py_Initialize();

    python::class_<ORM>("ORM")
        .def("print", print1)
        .def("print", print2)
        .def("print", print3).staticmethod("print");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for everything, I tested it and it works like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help!